# ***HELP*** Test/Mock: Service Class using Rest Template, Response and HTTP Entities, Exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, service, request, mockito, resttemplate

I have a service class, with for readability purpose, I have provided the code with dummy variables and objects. I am trying to write a JUNIT test class for the service, primarily with Mockito. No matter how hard I try, I am not able to hit the method *serviceMethod* irrespective of using spy/mock. I have also included a test, following the main class.

I know I am missing something here, but doesn't cross my mind. I need an eye to review this and let me know how I can write a proper test class for this and obtain coverage for the method.

(P.S. all the necessary imports are in-place and not pasted here to keep this concise)

Thanks in advance!

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceClass.class);

    @Autowired
    String stringUrl;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public void serviceMethod(ModelObject model) {

        try {

            HttpEntity<ModelObject> request = new HttpEntity<>(model);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(stringUrl,
                    HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

            LOGGER.info(response.getBody() + "and " + response.getStatusCode());
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException exception) {
            LOGGER.info(exception.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException exception) {
            LOGGER.info(exception.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }

    }
```

Sample Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class ServiceClassTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceClass serviceClass;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testServiceMethod() {

        ServiceClass spy = Mockito.spy(serviceClass);
//      ServiceClass spy = mock(ServiceClass.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
        doNothing().when(spy).serviceMethod(Mockito.any(ModelObject.class));

        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(spy).serviceMethod(Mockito.any(ModelObject.class));

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<ModelObject>>any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any()))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, call your method under test in your test. Then, spying on service under test just to tell it to call real method (which is the default) makes no sense. Mocking service under test makes no sense as well.

Comment: @Lesiak thanks for that. what could be other suggestions? sorry if I'm asking silly qq.s, I'm a beginner

Comment: Well, testing method that only logs something is kind of difficult. Don't you intend to return the response from your method?

Comment: Yes @Lesiak. I would need to test the functionality of this method

Comment: If you intend to return something, then make assertions on the returned object.